# sql - How to save the products purchased by the customer and show them on a HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, sql, html

I am studying SQL and PHP, I searched for something related to my question but found nothing.
I managed to make a basic register system using sessions, and now I'm trying to go a step further allowing logged in users buy products. The function that determinates if the user is logged in or not is:

```
function loggedin()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['name']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Therefore, I use to identify:

```
if (loggedin() == true)
```

I do not know how to proceed. From what I've been searching, I must create a table for the products.
The table for the customers I already have, but I do not know how to go dynamically adding the products that the customer purchases. I need to relate the customer id with the id of the product?
I was thinking in an HTML select that contains all products. But how to relate the product selected in the HTML select with the same product there in the database? Using the HTML select, the user will select the desired product, then it is added to his account and then displayed in an HTML table on a separate page containing all the products purchased by that user.
I'm new to PHP and SQL, I would ask humbly a little help for me to understand the logic and put me in the right way to achieve my purpose.

Comment: I suspect this may be closed as being too broad for Stack Overflow...

Comment: I can recommend [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005436.do) to guide you in the direction you want to learn.

Comment: I'm concerned that this user is creating a system that will be dealing with Credit Card numbers with their lack of experience this is not a good starting project.

Comment: @cmorrissey To be honest I'm trying to do this to apply in my restaurant for customers to make online orders, no credit cards involved.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, you need to create 3 tables

- customer
- product
- purchases

Every time a customer makes a purchase, enter the customer id, and product id, into the purchases table. You then have a record of every purchase which you can query.

Comment: Hmm... I'm beginning to understand it better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need a product table that has your products for example:

```
product_id | description | price
```

You need a users table, as you stated

```
user_id | password | name
```

And probably most important, a linking/reference/junction table. This table associates users with products

```
user_id | product_ids
```

For some more information on reference tables have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) and [here](https://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/understanding-a-sql-junction-table/)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at it! I think it will help me get to where I want.